# Is it okay to use inequalities in functions?

Tags: functions, notation

For example, I want to say that the gradient of a function is negative for all $x<0.$ Is it okay to write $f'(x<0)<0$?

Comment: You can simply write that $f^\prime(x) < 0$ for all $x < 0$.

Comment: Depends on who your teacher and audience is.  I'd understand and accept it from a fellow mathematician at my level (although I think $f'(x;x< 0)$ would be clearer.  But if a fellow mathematician wrote it for a student, I'd argue that it would confuse and frustrate the student.  If a student wrote it I'd think the student didn't know what he was doing and I'd (perhaps very unfairly) argue that the it simply is ungramatical and doesn't make any sense.  Best to simply state "For all x < 0, f'(x) < 0".

Comment: I will confess I have typed things like $3^{970 \equiv 2 \mod [\phi(10)=4]} \equiv 9 \mod 10$  to save typing even though it's a clearly an abuse of notation. So I can't really criticize.